# Django error: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So I am making a django project, I have this code:

My Models.py:

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            return None
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user, 
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False


class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    objects   = ThreadManager()
```

My views.py:

```
def Messages(request, *args, **kwargs):
    Chats = Thread.objects.all()
    User1 = Thread.first.all()
    context = {
        'content': Chats,
        'user1': User1
    }
    return render(request, "chat/messages.html", context)
```

I dont know why I cannot use the all method, I want to get the firts object of my thread class model, but when I use it, this appears ('ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'), does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this statement,  `User1 = Thread.first.all()`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I am trying to get the data of the variable 'first' in my model thread

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to access the first object doesn't make any sense. It should be `Thread.objects.all().first()` not `Thread.first.all()`.

[See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Comment: yes, but the problem is that I dont want the first object, I want the data of the variables first and second in my model thread.